# Sense new file in AWS S3 from GCP services and move to file to GCS

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to sense new file uploaded in a aws s3 bucket (file has dynamic name and can land in any key in that specific key) and move that file to GCS.

1. I tried with Airflow S3KeySensor and patterns. but feel that is it picking up every file that matches (not new one) from the s3 bucket every-time.
2. Is there a way to trigger gcp cloud function with an S3Event?

Comment: Is this a viable solution for your usecase?: "Upload file to S3 -> Trigger AWS Lambda function -> Move file to GCS using Lambda function OR Trigger Cloud Function which would move the file to GCS"

Comment: we cant use aws components.. can upload file to s3 trigger a cloud function to movie file to gcs?

Comment: Based on your restrictions, at the present moment, you might need to pull, unfortunately. What is your maximum accepted latency?

Comment: Please clarify your environment. You are using an S3 bucket. Why do you say **we cant use aws components..**? You can either set up events to be notified of new objects in S3 or you will need to scan/list/poll for new objects. If you do not own/manage the bucket/account, you will not be able to set up events.

Comment: @JohnHanley i meant we cannot use any other components except for s3.

Comment: Cloud functions can not directly over the S3 amazon bucket,  since there is not a way to connect the CF to the amazon bucket a Lambda function could be helpful to trigger.

Comment: ohh okay @vicalderon .. got it.. so we would definitely have to use lambda in between.. thank you for confirming that..

Comment: I have not implemented this, but you might be able to use Amazon EventBridge to call a Google Cloud Function on an S3 event. EventBridge supports calling outside AWS using REST API calls. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-destinations-with-amazon-eventbridge/

Answer (score 2):

This is community answer formed by users answers.

Since CF can not connect directly received a trigger from S3 amazon buckets,it is needed a Lambda function. Letting the flow on this way:

"Upload file to S3 -> Trigger AWS Lambda function -> Move file to GCS using Lambda function OR Trigger Cloud Function which would move the file to GCS"